# How can I change one label out of many by right clicking one of them

Tags: vb.net

I have some simple code. It changes the `BorderStyle` property of a Label by right-clicking. Nothing fancy, but still. However, I have *twenty* labels. Is there a simpler way of doing this instead of "copy-paste" this code 20 times?

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
        Handles Label1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            If Label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None Then
                Label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            Else
                Label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            End If
        End If
End Sub
Private Sub Label2_MouseDown...
...
End Sub
```

Comment: You can simply register the same event handler on every label and inside the Sub find out which one ist the current target by inspecting the `sender`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either create a custom control which inherits from Label and has the behaviour you want, or you could write a handler which works out which control it is responding to from the `sender` parameter.

The latter, presented first here, is simpler for a one-off, but the former would be more re-usable, and you wouldn't have to maintain the list of Labels for the AddHandler.

```
Sub Label_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Dim lbl = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        If lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None Then
            lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Else
            lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        End If

    End If

End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each l In {Label1, Label2}
        AddHandler l.MouseDown, AddressOf Label_MouseDown
    Next

End Sub
```

The `AddHandler` line connects the `MouseDown` event of each of the `Label`s to the specified event handler. (You can add more than one event handler to an event, if needed.)

---

For a control (your very own custom one) derived from an existing control (a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` in this case), let's call it `BorderedControl`, you can follow the instructions at [How to: Inherit from Existing Windows Forms Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-inherit-from-existing-windows-forms-controls) (it's too close to plagiarism to copy it to here), and then your code for the control might look like:

```
Public Class BorderedLabel
    Inherits Label

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(e As MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            If Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None Then
                Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
            Else
                Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
            End If

        End If

        MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)

    End Sub

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

End Class
```

After you have built your project after adding that code, you will find a new control, named "BorderedLabel", in the ToolBox. You can drag that onto the form "design surface" and it will behave just like an ordinary Label except that it will have your BorderStyle-changing code incorporated automatically.

Comment: For the record, there's no real reason to use `AddHandler` at all here. In the case of multiple controls added in the designer just select all the controls, open the Properties and click the Events button, then double-click the event of interest. That will create a handler with all the selected controls in the `Handles` clause. You can also select an existing event handler from the drop-down if you add a new control.

Comment: In the case of a custom control, it is more appropriate to override the `OnMouseDown` method than to create a handler for the `MouseDown` event. There's also no need to cast the `sender` in the case of a custom control if you do use an event handler because you know that it will be the current object that raised the event, so you can jjst use `Me`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you. I have updated the custom control code accordingly.